# good way to seperate List<Integer> into 5 lists of chunks around the 5 minimums

Tags: java, list, math, min

Ok guys, time to get creative. 
I have a list of integers, and want to preserve the integers in the 5 green boxes below.
I thought about finding the 5 minimums, and then going left and right from each one until the next integer is a certain distance too far. However this may be difficult to do as the last to boxes have some scattered values that I would like to maintain.

So cliff notes,
have list of integers that i want to make 5 lists of integers from, each one of the 5 lists holding the values of one of the green boxes.

I am sorry if this question seems dumb, I was just wanting to see if other people had better ways of going about this then the one I mentioned above.

[image: List of integers]

Edit:
Perhaps a Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm would help? If only I could understand math books xD. I swear math explanations are never written in English, but if someone just shows me the use, and how to, I get it and understand it. Then I can go read it out of a book again and just be confused all over again!

Comment: Do you have an algorithm for determining the green boxes? Or is that what you're asking?

Comment: No, i drew those in paint to highlight for stackoverflow what i wanted to keep.

Comment: I suppose if I know the max range of value that I would like to keep from each minimum, I could just travel left and right from each minimum until currentInteger > (minimumInteger + maxDifference)

Comment: If you know that this is going to be the general shape of your data, you can try fitting a polynomial (or whatever) to it and looking at the second derivative.

Comment: Levenberg-Marquardt is probably not what you want, that is used to create a line that is a least squares solution to all of your points.

Comment: ahhh, so if I take the 5 batches of minimums, then perhaps after I want the Levenberg-Marquardt. The reason for doing this is That we are trying to hit a variable target that this set of data would help us pinpoint in a very accurate manner. So we are using this to 'calibrate', basically we know what each of the batches of minimums should represent. by analyzing them, and knowing what they are approx = to, we are able to get a set of constants from which to normalize other unknown data.

Comment: Can you find the least squares line through the points?  It seems that  should separate the green boxes of minimums from the infrared boxes of maximums.  And then you can decide how big of a jump means that you've exited the box to the left or the right.

Comment: brilliant ^ let me try this

Comment: @Teepeemm: if your comment were an answer, it would get my vote…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be a possible solution:

Let call your list of integer P[n].

- define a new list of point, we call it MAX[n], calculated this way:

if ((MAX[n] < P[n]) || (n == 0))
   MAX[n] = P[n];
else
   MAX[n] = MAX[n-1];

in this way, MAX[n] list will be the green line above your graph:[image: MAX[n]]

FIRST SOLUTION:
to identify the points inside the green boxes, you just have to calculate the incremental ratio of your P list, and check when its absolute value is smaller than a threshold:

I = [P[n+1] - P[n]] / [T[n+1] - T[n]]

so a point is into the green box if I is below a threshold and P is below MAX:

if ((P[n] < MAX[n]) && (ABS(I) < DER_THRESHOLD))
   // your point is inside the green box

from your graph, roughtly, you could put DER_THRESHOLD = 5.

SECOND SOLUTION:
calculate a new list of integers, called this time AVG[n] like that:

AVG[n] = (MAX[n] + P[n]) / 2

this will end in the red line (sorry for the ugly graph, did it by hand):

[image: AVG[n]]

and now you can identify green boxes just checking if your P[n] is below AVG[n].

This solution could be even better using some kind of low filtering in AVG calculation.

Comment: This was awesome. Very simple, very easy to adjust and manipulate. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the least squares fit line through the points, and then look at whether the points are above or below the line.  That will split your points into the five green boxes below the line, and the six infrared boxes above the line.  It will also include the points inbetween the boxes, but those will be easy to exclude because of the big jump before or after the point that should be excluded.  But it's also looking like you may have trouble at the top right of this data set.

Comment: This nearly worked, but in the end was proving difficult to get just the right parts. However was also better idea then what I was doing. Thank you.